# VS Code Azure Functions: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, azure-functions

Trying to deploy Azure Functions written in Python and looks like the only option to do that is through VS Code.
I have Python and Azure Functions extensions, and normally use PyCharm with Anaconda interpreter.
I also have azure-functions-core-tools installed and calling "func" in PS works.
In the VS Code I create a virtual environment as it suggests. But when tyring to debug  any Azure Function (using one of their templates for now) I get the error above.
As far as I understand it tries to install "azure-functions" module as specified in the "requirements.txt" file and tries to do that with pip. pip works normally if I use it through Anaconda prompt or with my global env python, but I have to use the virtual environment created by VS Code for this one.
Any suggestions on how to get through this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is Python installed? It sounds like your Python installation is lacking the `ssl` module which is required to make HTTPS requests.

Comment: I solved it just a couple days ago actually. The problem was with the virtual environment that VS Code was creating for my Azure Function project. By deciding not to use a .venv and using the python installed on my machine instead, everything worked. But honestly, working with VS Code on this was such a pain. It says you can change interpreter that you are using locally (as in, use anaconda env instead of my global env) but nothing really happens.

Comment: "Nothing really happens" how? As in you don't think the switched interpreter/environment is picked up? Or it didn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just solved the problem after wasting my valuable whole afternoon. The problem lies on the side of Anaconda.

As you described in your question, `pip` works normally *(only) in your Anaconda prompt*. Which means, it doesn't work anywhere outside, no matter in a CMD or a PowerShell (although `pip` and `conda` seem work outside of the prompt, SSL requests get somehow always refused). However, VS Code, when you simply press F5 instead of using `func start` command, uses an external PowerShell to call pip. No wonder it'll fail.

The problem can be solved, when you install Anaconda on Windows 10, by **choosing to add Anaconda's root folder to PATH.** This being said, Anaconda's installer strongly doesn't recommend choosing this option (conflicts with other apps blabla)... And if you try to install Anaconda through some package manager such as scoop, it'll install it without asking you for this detail, which is logical.

The "fun" part is philosophically Anaconda itself doesn't suggest using `conda` or `pip` command outside Anaconda Prompt, while other apps want and may have to do it the other way. Very very confusing and annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. The recomended aproach is to install anaconda without choosing to add Anaconda's root folder to PATH and then manually adding it.
In an new comand line (windows) run: 
    set PATH=%PATH%;[path_to_conda]\env\[your_conda_env];[path_to_conda]\env\[your_conda_env]\Library\bin;[path_to_conda]\env\[your_conda_env]\Scripts